# How to identify if latitude and longitude are part of particular city?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

I have a collection of latitude and longitude. If I provide City name(for eg. Chicago), how can I find out only those lat/longs which are within the provided City's boundary?

The end product would be map of City with location pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) requests for latlng with `result_type=locality` parameter. The response will contains a name of city this coordinate belongs to.

For example, coordinate 41.878253,-87.72995 will return 'Chicago, IL, USA':

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=41.878253%2C-87.72995&result_type=locality&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Coordinate 41.970722,-88.420715 will return 'Campton Hills, IL, USA':

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=41.970722%2C-88.420715&result_type=locality&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Hope this helps!